Alias interfaces by adding an environment parameter as a condition in services.yaml
I have two repositories implementing the same interface.

App\Repository\RepoA
App\Repository\Legacy\RepoA

I also have added the USE_LEGACY env variable(as a parameter in the services.yaml as well):
parameters:
    use_legacy: '%env(bool:USE_LEGACY)%'

What I wanna achieve is, if USE_LEGACY is set to true the interface when called will call the repository from legacy, if not, it will call the other(non-legacy) repository.
So far I tried:
services:
      App\Repository\Interface\RepoAInterface: 
        alias: '@=service("App\Repository" ~ (parameter("use_legacy:") == false ? "\\RepoA" : "\Legacy\\RepoA"))'

But this is not working. Is there any solution?
FYI, I'm using Symfony 6.4 and PHP 8.3

Use factory class to dynamically build services:
services:
   App\Repository\Interface\RepoAInterface:
       factory: '@App\Factory\RepoAFactory'
       arguments:
           - '%use_legacy%'

use App\Repository\RepoA;
use App\Repository\Legacy\RepoA as LegacyRepoA;
use App\Repository\Interface\RepoAInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\AutowireLocator;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

class RepoAFactory
{
    public function __construct(
        #[AutowireLocator([
            RepoA::class,
            LegacyRepoA::class,
        ])]
        private ContainerInterface $locator,
    ) {
    }

    public function __invoke(bool $useLegacy): RepoAInterface
    {
        return $useLegacy === true
            ? $this->locator->get(LegacyRepoA::class)
            : $this->locator->get(RepoA::class);
    }
}


Hey Justinas thanks a lot for the answer!
I just wanted to know is it even possible adding conditions based on any env parameter as part of aliases?

@ÇlirimKastrati If using service factory, you can use whatever fits to find out proper service implementation. I have never tried using dynamically built service ID's, but I don't think it's very readable and almost 100% sure that static code analysis will skip that part, leading to even wors way to refactor legacy code

The short answer is no. Symfony does a bunch of pre-processing (aka compiling) and stores the results in a static cache. Env variables are of course checked on every request. Not the sort of thing you can cache. The factory approach is your best bet though even then you might have trouble with auto-wiring and such.
